# Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in............. on line 200

Please tell me the solution for it. Below I have posted my whole code till line 200

```
<?php
function my_session_start() {
    session_start();
}

function escape($str) {
    $clean_str = ( get_magic_quotes_gpc ()) ? mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($str))) : mysql_real_escape_string(trim($str));
    return $clean_str;
}

function _addslashes($str) {   
    $clean_str = ( get_magic_quotes_gpc ()) ? $str : addslashes($str);
    return $clean_str;
}

function clean($str) {
    $clean_str = stripslashes (trim($str));
    return $clean_str;
}

function checkbox_value($str) {
    if(isset($_POST[$str]) && $_POST[$str]=="on") return 1;
    return 0;    
}

function generate_random() {
    $str = md5(uniqid(rand(),1));
    return $str;
}

function html_link($str) {
    $str=correct_href($str);
    $ret='<a href="'.$str.'">'.$str.'</a>';
    return $ret;
}

function correct_href($str) {
    if(!trim($str)) return;
    if(strcmp(substr($str,0,7),"http://") && strcmp(substr($str,0,8),"https://")) $str="http://".$str;
    return $str;
}

function correct_number_format($str) {
    $app = new appearance();
    $appearance = $app->getAll();
    $decimals = $appearance['number_format_decimals']; 
    $point = $appearance['number_format_point'];  
    $separator = $appearance['number_format_separator']; 
    $ereg_str = "/^[0-9]*".$point."*[0-9]+".$separator."*[0-9]*$/";
    $ereg_str = str_replace(".", "\.", $ereg_str);
    if(preg_match($ereg_str, $str)) return 1;
    return 0;    
}

function correct_numeric($str) {
    global $appearance_settings;
    $point = $appearance_settings['number_format_point'];
    $separator = $appearance_settings['number_format_separator'];
    // replace 
    $str = str_replace($point,"#",$str);
    $str = str_replace($separator,"",$str);
    $str = str_replace("#",".",$str);
    return $str;
}

function correct_price($str) {
    global $appearance_settings;
    $point = $appearance_settings['price_format_point'];
    $separator = $appearance_settings['price_format_separator'];
    // replace 
    $str = str_replace($point,"#",$str);
    $str = str_replace($separator,"",$str);
    $str = str_replace("#",".",$str);
    return $str;    
}
```

Comment: What is line 200 of the code you posted? I don't see `number_format()` anywhere in that code, except in a custom function...?

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: its a empty line. Please tell me the solution to remove it. I will be very glad. thanks

Comment: where is number_format()?, you're supplying it with a string instead of a floating point number (double).

Comment: The solution is to pass a `double` to `number_format` not a `string` ... the clue is in the error message.

Comment: line 199 is empty with whitespaces

number_format is in line 111,119, 121..

thank you all I am very glad to get help from you

CD001 Brother can you please give me an example to pass double to number_format

Comment: How are you calling your functions?

Comment: and where exactly to put it above I have shown my code till line 200 please tell me where to pass double

Comment: please take a look at my above code and tell me what exactly I did wrong and how to fix my error. thanks

Comment: anyone up?Please I need to fix it ASAP

Comment: Read Tim and Koen's comment again. The function throwing an error **is not in your supplied code**. Maybe you have supplied the wrong file?

Comment: @Jason: good blog post. Minor spell errors: `please swtich` (switch), `preceeding` (preceding), `perser` (parser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either format_price($str) or format_int($str) where this is occurring I would do the following change:

```
$result = number_format($str, $decimals, $point, $th_separator);
```

to

```
$result = number_format((int)$str, $decimals, $point, $th_separator);
```

if number contains pence use

```
$result = number_format((float)$str, $decimals, $point, $th_separator);
```